# function only evaluates first row of df

Tags: r

I wrote a function that checks if a string is empty (or only contains spaces) or not. However, when I try to apply it to a data frame, the function just returns FALSE one time for every column. I want the function to work similar to the is.na() function that evaluates every element of a data frame individually.

```
is_empty <- function(x) {
 result <- gsub(" ", "", x)
 ifelse(is.na(result), return(FALSE), return(result == ""))
}

> is_empty("")      # TRUE
> is_empty("   ")   # TRUE
> is_empty(0)       # FALSE
> is_empty(NA)      # FALSE
> is_empty("foo")   # FALSE

> df = data.frame(c("",2,""), c(4, "  ", 6), c("", 8, 9), c(1,2,4))

> is_empty(df)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> is.na(df)
      c.....2..... c.4........6. c.....8..9. c.1..2..4.
 [1,]        FALSE         FALSE       FALSE      FALSE
 [2,]        FALSE         FALSE       FALSE      FALSE
 [3,]        FALSE         FALSE       FALSE      FALSE
```

(I know that NA means, that we don't know, whether the element is empty or not, but for practical reasons, I want it to be FALSE.)

My function minus the gsub() function works as expected but the function can then only detect empty cells without spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to write function `is_empty` which works on vectors and not on dataframe.

```
is_empty <- function(x) {
    trimws(x) == ''
    #You can also use
    #gsub('\\s+', '', x) == ''
}

is_empty(c("",2,"   "))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Now to apply to every column of dataframe use `sapply`/`lapply` :

```
df = data.frame(a = c("",2,""), b = c(4, "  ", 6), c = c("", 8, 9), d = c(1,2,4))
sapply(df, is_empty)   

#         a     b     c     d
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Obviously if you want the function to work on dataframes you can take `sapply` part inside the function.